# Which type of set convergence is given by $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x,A_n)=d(x,A)$ for all $x\in X$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $A\subseteq X$ be a subset of $X$, and let $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of subsets of $X$ such that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}d(x,A_n)=d(x,A), \quad \forall x\in X \tag{1}$$

where $d(x,Y)=\inf_{y\in Y}d(x,y)$.

In what sense does $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge to $A$? This is weaker than usual set convergence such as $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=A$. For example, under definition $(1)$, the sequence of sets $\{1\},\{1/2\},\{1/3\},\dots$ converges to the set $\{0\}$. Is there a name for this type of convergence?

Comment: Let $A_n$ be the first $n$ rationals and $A$ be the reals. No name that I am aware of.

Comment: For set convergence, see convergence in the sense of Kuratowski-Painleve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence